# Can I make all viewable windows active (responsive to mouse clicks)?

Tags: macos

For example, if I have 2 monitors and 3 opened browser windows, and I want to click a link on inactive window I have to click 2 times—first to activate a window and the second time to click a link.

Is there a way to make all viewable windows active so that they respond immediately to mouse clicks without having to be focused first?

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.6.